# Does anyone know how you access LocalStorage via LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Does anyone know how you access LocalStorage via LWC? I need to access LocalStorage from my LWC but it always retrieves back as 'null'. I simply used localStorage.getItem('My_Key_Item'). What's weird is if I try checking the value via console, I get the result as I need but not with LWC. With LWC, its always 'null'. Also, the session storage is created via one of the experience site pages.

Comment: Local storage works seamlessly in LWC. Can you share the code sample here? Also, I would recommend you to check out my blog post on the same - [Client Side Caching and Data Persistence in LWC using Local Storage](https://www.forcetrails.com/2023/10/lwc-client-side-caching-with-localStorage.html)